# How do I disable and enable macros on the fly?

Tags: vba, excel, visibility

I would like to test an Excel VBA app I made.
However the VBA code messes around with the visibility of cells and that's a pest when editing the sheet.

Is there an option is enable and disable macro's on the fly without having to

```
Close the sheet
Change the macro settings
Reopen the sheet
Close the sheet
Change the macro settings.
etc.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't enable / disable macros from an opened workbook *on the fly*.
Yet, you shouldn't have to because macros are only triggered thanks to a user click.

The only case I would see is for the Event Procedures (`Worksheet_Change` or else).
You could then create procedures to activate / deactivate events and call them from buttons in your worksbook:

```
Sub enableEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub disableEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

You can also try these tips from [Chris Pearson website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) using global vars you would change depending on your needs:

```
Public AbortChangeEvent As Boolean
```

And check if afterwards:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If AbortChangeEvent = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    ' rest of code here
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 For enable/disable events, that is actually useful, because it leaves UDF's working, whilst disabling the sheet disrupting stuff.

Answer (score 6):

To disable macros on the fly, use "Application.EnableEvents = False" via the Immediate window in the VBA editor (and "Application.EnableEvents = True" to turn them back on).

Comment: This is just a duplicate of the existing answer, voting to delete.

Comment: @Johan: Why would you delete it? The existing answer doesn't mention the "Immediate" window; while this answer could (and probably should) be reworded, it is a shorter version of the original answer that works for an ad hoc test and hence is useful. (The answerer doesn't seem to have enough repo to comment or edit...)

Comment: The question asked "on the fly". Writing additional macros is not "on the fly". This is the simplest, most direct approach; it does not require adding any additional code to the project.

Comment: To open 'immediate window', while in VBA editor screen, select View at the upper right hand corner and then you'll see it to click on.

Answer (score 5):

You can also hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when you open a document to disable macros.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I needed to paste formulas in a workbook that ran a macro clearing the clipboard upon workbook activation. Great pain resolved. I now open the workbook with macros disabled, paste what needs to be pasted, save and close the workbook and reopen with macros active.

Comment: This used to work, but can't seem to get this work in Microsoft 365. Unless I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: This was changed in an update in Excel 365 back in 2018/2019. I can get it to work ca 50% of the times I open a file if I close all Excel windows and then open the file while holding the SHIFT key.

Answer (score 2):

As of Excel 2010* there's actually an option on the "Developer" tab which allows you to disable macros as easy as ABC. [Design Mode lets you do just that!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxo5p.png)

*Maybe even earlier versions.

Comment: Can you enter design mode with VBA? (This question is about programatic control)

Comment: Where does it say in the question that macros should be programmatically activated or deactivated? This is what I think most users would expect as the accepted answer when having this issue and finding this question.

Answer (score 1):

I often fire Macros when opening a workbook but sometimes I don't want the Macro to fire so I can work on the code. So what I put a Macro in a separate workbook that does the following:

1. Disables macros
2. Opens the workbook in question
3. Enables macros
4. Then closes the original workbook
5. Leaves the second workbook open
   Here's the code:

```
Sub OpenClose()

    'Opens Workbook below with Macors disabled

    'After it is open Macros are enabled

    'This Workbook then closes without saving changes, leaving only the workbook below open

    '************************************************************
    'User only needs to change the workbook name on the next line
    WorkbookToOpenNoMacros = "Gaby.xlsm"
    '************************************************************

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Application.Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & WorkbookToOpenNoMacros)

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    wb.Saved = True

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Office 2013 and I found a button on the VBA window that did this for me very easily.

There's a play, pause and stop button on the toolbar. In Excel, they are actually called, Run Macro, Break and Reset.

Click the Break button (pause) and any running macros should stop running. I only tested it on one macro but seems reasonable to presume that this will work in general.

Also, I believe those buttons were there for many versions of Excel, so it's worth checking earlier versions.

Comment: That stops a currently running macro, it doesn't stop macros from running in the first place.